# OS X clipboard with language C

Tags: c, macos, clipboard

Is there a way to communicate with Mac OS X clipboard in language C (without Obj-C/Cocoa) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way might be to call the command line programs `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.

Answer (score 2):

[Pasteboard Manager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Pasteboard_Prog_Guide/paste_intro/paste_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001439-CH201-DontLinkElementID_21)